# Styling Issue with Internet Explorer - Most likely Easy Solution

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, drupal

I have a relatively easy issue that I need fixed mainly because I haven't come across it before and don't know how to go about fixing the issue.

Near the bottom of the page there are four images grouped together under the title "Photo Gallery". In Firefox and Google Chrome, the photo gallery is displayed correctly, with the correct formatting being the images side-by-side rather than the incorrect style of stacked images. Thanks!

**Below is the code for the individual image fields (with the only difference being .odd rather than .even**

```
.field.field-name-field-photo-gallery.field-type-image.field-label-above .field-items .field-item.even {
width: auto;
display: inline;
margin-top: 0px;
top: 0;
```

(Incorrect Image Gallery)
[image]

(Correct Image Gallery)
[image]

Comment: The issue can be seen with this page: 

http://arvadahistory.org/content/5712-yarrow-st-arvada-co-80002

Comment: Which IE version? It works correctly in IE11.

Comment: try using display: inline-block; instead inline, or change the div's to span. ie got some weird bugs with inline elements

Answer (score 0):

For something like this it would be worth considering using a grid system,

[Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) is my preferred option, its inclusion in a project would result in code like

Assuming the design is 12 col,

```
@include span(3 of 9);
```

On your images (Selectors way too long too) would achieve with margin the design you are after.
Susy outputs floats by default, so if you did want to do it manually, do some simple math to work out % widths and apply floats. Works in all browsers and doesn't give the weird 3px extra that inline elements get.